# progress bar change value from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkScores =  function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/countScoreCh',
        success: function(response) {

      //some code

        }
    });
}
  $(function() {
     $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: 50
 });
 });

</script>
```

**controller**

```
public function countScoreCh(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $data['getScore'] = $this->lawmodel->battleUserID($id);
    foreach($data['getScore'] as $row){
        $scoreCH = $row->challengerScore;
        echo json_encode(
        array(
        'scoreCH' => $scoreCH,
                )
            );
    }
}
```

**EDITED**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var checkScores =  function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/countScoreCh',
        success: function(response) {

      //some code that will be call to the progressbar value:

        }
    });
}
  $(function() {
     $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: //the value will be base on the result of the controller $scoreCH
 });
 });

</script>
```

How can i update the value on the progress bar base on the output of the controller?
since the controller use `json_encode`. if the controller output is 50 then the value of the progressbar will be change to 50.

Need help..i dont know if the json_encode is the proper way to use it....but any solution will do..

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the json from your ajax call and apply the value `data.progress` on your progressbar object:

Short example:

```
var checkScores =  function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/countScoreCh',
        success: function(response) {
        dataType: "json", // data type json
        success: function(data){
            var progress = data.progess;
            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
                value: progress
            });
        }


        });
    });
```

Then your PHP is going to look like

```
public function countScoreCh(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $data['getScore'] = $this->lawmodel->battleUserID($id);
    foreach($data['getScore'] as $row){
        $scoreCH = $row->challengerScore;
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'scoreCH' => $scoreCH,
                'progress' => 50
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: i edit my post a little..i think there is some misunderstanding..my problem is how to change the value in progressbar base on the ajax call or controller output. not just putting a value to be call to the progressbar value..:))

Comment: and also..when i put the `$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar` below the `success:function` the progress bar will not be displayed..

Comment: You have to put the progressbar code IN the succes function. That function handles the success of the request you are trying to make. The example i gave you is changing the value of the progressbar based on the ajax call, you only need to replace 50 in the PHP code with your value...

Comment: I updated my answer so the code is only showing neccessary parts.

Comment: putting `$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
                value: progress
            });` inside the `success:function` will not be display..and i dont understand why..Y_Y

Comment: Try logging with `alert(data)` or `console.log(data)` what the response of `data` is... Maybe that could be useful.